# Robot Framework: Re Run Failed Test Cases

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, robotframework

In Robot Automation, how to re-run the failed test case immediately if it is failed, before going to another test case execution.
For instance,

```
*** Test Cases ***
Login User And Create Another User
      Login User ....
      Create Another User ...

Login With New User
      Login User..

Test Function ABC
     .....
     .....
```

Since one test has a dependency on another test, I need to re-run the failed case immediately after it is failed. Before executing another test.

Answer (score 2):

In one word, you can't, and you shouldn't; a case is a case, with binary outcome. And if you have dependencies between tests, that's a smelly design; try to change it to a pre-condition (env setup) for the second case, so it is atomic.
Disclaimer: this rant is for the automatic re-execution in a single run. After a run has finished, RF has baked-in functionality to re-execute just the failed ones (so flaky tests are given the chance to succeed); but as I understood your question, you are not asking for the latter.

---

In two words, if you really need to do it, you can; extract the whole test case in a keyword, and call it inside `Wait Until Keyword Succeeds`, giving it 2 (or more?) attempts:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test Function ABC
     Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    2 times     100ms     The Actual Test For Function ABC

*** Keywords ***
The Actual Test For Function ABC
     .....
     .....
```